# Autofill bootstrap grid

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, flexbox

Is it possible with bootstrap to auto-fill the spaces in my layout?

I have a grid with `cols-xs-6` and only one item with `col-xs-12`, but all this data is dynamic and the `col-xs-12` container doesn't always show. However, when it shows, I need the next container to fill the white space on the image.

[image]

Is it possible to do that with Bootstrap? or flex layout?

The result should be something like: 
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Flexbox order property (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order) to reorder some or all flex items (Bootstrap 4.β grid uses Flexbox).

➡️ **[Demo on Bootply](https://www.bootply.com/1R9uzZiMYg)** with both cases: empty space or not before `.col-sm-12` (e.g. latter one is even or odd).

```
/* Add .customized on a parent/ancestor of Bootstrap grid .row element to
 * allow item next to a full width one to occupy empty space before it if
 * there's any (e.g. if the wide one is even
 */
.customized .col-sm-12:nth-child(even) {
  order: 1;
}
.customized .col-sm-12:nth-child(even) ~ .col-sm-6 {
  order: 1;
}
.customized .col-sm-12:nth-child(even) + .col-sm-6 {
  order: 0;
}
```

- 2nd and 3rd rules have the same specificity and we want the 3rd one to override the 2nd one so it must appear in that order.
- Default value `0` will apply on all items *before* the wide one and if there's no wide one and if the wide one is odd thus no empty space before it.

---

EDIT:
Old answer which does something different and doesn't fulfill requirements of OP:

You can modify Bootstrap grid with CSS alone in order to achieve this.
With Flexbox grid (here with BS4β version):

`/* Add .customized on a parent/ancestor of Bootstrap grid .row element to allow half-width items to be full width if there's room for that */
    /* not for the last item: it'll still be half wide */
    /* It overrides BS4β .col-sm-6 { flex: 0 0 50%; max-width: 50%; } */
    .customized .col-sm-6:not(:last-child) {
      flex-grow: 1;
      max-width: 100%;
    }`

It allows any `.col-sm-6` to occupy whole width of its container:

- *if* there's room for that, e.g. if there isn't another element on the same row
- *and* - as shown in your screenshot - if it isn't the last one.

➡️ **[Demo on Bootply](https://www.bootply.com/rVbXszzmP0)** with both cases: `.col-sm-6` before or after `.col-sm-12`.

Comment: That is an awesome solution. Although the best solution is to create the same looking as the second container, without changing the lorem ipsum 4 up.

Comment: Bad copy-paste in my 2nd test case where I exchanged the labelling 3 and 4, sorry about that: [updated](https://www.bootply.com/Ir26GnSfKj). But now I see you didn't want 2 full widths items but reordering (the lack of labelling disturbed me I guess). Flexbox [order](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order) (MDN) allows that, I'll update my answer with a method that fulfills your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

twiter bootstrap works hand in hand like say .col-md-12 (1/st half) .col-md-12 (secound half) they most be written in complete other, if this rule is neglected say for bootstrap 3 , where float css property is used it would float the next parent div to it , bootstarp 4 uses flex-box which is still no better solution.

i would advise you use masonary for that, just that you would need to specify the width of each column, i think this is a better olution to the issue.

masonary fills blank spaces with exisiting parent div , floating them with each other mainting a fixed width  or a responsive width px and percentage.

i had once used masonary in one of my template i was creating.

here maybe this pen would help.

1. https://codepen.io/desandro/pen/eJJEXd
2. https://codepen.io/desandro/pen/myBxD?selected_tag=masonry&

   and you could make a jquery call like so
   $('.#container').masonry({
     itemSelector: '.item',
     columnWidth: '.item',
     percentPosition: true
   });

and html could look like this

```
<div id="container">
  <div class="col-md-3"><img src="https://lorempixel.com/300/350/nature" /></div>
  <div class="col-md-3"><img src="https://lorempixel.com/300/300/nature" /></div>
  <div class="col-md-3"><img src="https://lorempixel.com/300/450/nature" /></div>
</div>
```

they are other methods provided in there doc page to help customize it further